# Array from specific keys in a dictionaries array?

Tags: swift

I have an array of dictionaries : `[[String:String]]`

From **every** dictionary in this array I want **only** the key `"name"` to be added into a **new** array.

I can loop over them obviously, but is there a way with *1 line* (similar to `array.keys` only with **specific** keys) ?

Comment: You mean you want the *value* for the `"name"` key in each dictionary to be added to a new array? Sounds like you're asking for `["name", "name", "name", ...]` ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `map` for that.

```
let nameArray = yourArray.map { $0["name"]! }
```

If all the dictionaries from array not contains `name` key then use `flatMap`.

```
let nameArray = yourArray.flatMap { $0["name"] }
```

Comment: BTW what if the array is [String:Any] ? and I need to use map to get the strings?

Comment: @Curnelious For map: `let nameArray = yourArray.map { $0["name"] as! String }` For flatMap: `let nameArray = yourArray.map { $0["name"] as? String }`