# Swift - Displaying JSON data in pie chart using charts

Tags: ios, swift, charts, alamofire

I am trying to display fetched JSON data in my pie chart with the help of Charts library. But unable to assign the array data to chart as the JSON data fetched is in the form of key-value pair and at the time of setting the chart, simple array is needed. Please help friends, any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

```
import UIKit
import Charts
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

class CertificateChartView: UIViewController {

    // Pie chart view
    @IBOutlet weak var pie: PieChartView!

    //Certificate Image Url
    let certificateImageURL = "--my url string--"

    // Temporary array dictionary
    var tempArray = [[String : AnyObject]]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

//        getCertificates()

        let months = ["Jan", "Feb","Mar"]
        let unitsSold = [25.0, 45.0, 36.0]
        setChart(dataPoints: months, values: unitsSold)
        pie.chartDescription?.text = ""
        pie.noDataText = "You need to provide data for the chart"

    }


//    function for Pie chart 
    func setChart(dataPoints: [String], values: [Double]) {
        var dataEntries: [ChartDataEntry] = []
        for i in 0..<dataPoints.count {
            let dataEntry1 = ChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: values[i], data: dataPoints[i] as AnyObject)
            dataEntries.append(dataEntry1)
        }
        //        print(dataEntries[0].data)
        let pieChartDataSet = PieChartDataSet(values: dataEntries, label: "")
        let pieChartData = PieChartData(dataSet: pieChartDataSet)
        pie.data = pieChartData
        pie.centerText = "Certificate"
        var colors: [UIColor] = []
        for _ in 0..<dataPoints.count {
            let red = Double(arc4random_uniform(256))
            let green = Double(arc4random_uniform(256))
            let blue = Double(arc4random_uniform(256))
            let color = UIColor(red: CGFloat(red/255), green: CGFloat(green/255), blue: CGFloat(blue/255), alpha: 1)
            colors.append(color)
        }
        pieChartDataSet.colors = colors
    }


    func getCertificates() {
        Alamofire.request(certificateImageURL).responseJSON { response in
            if((response.result.value) != nil) {
                let swiftyJsonVar = JSON(response.result.value!)
                if let resData = swiftyJsonVar["data"].arrayObject {
                    self.tempArray = resData as! [[String:AnyObject]]
//                    print(self.tempArray.count)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**JSON data**

```
 {
  data: [
    {
      cert_id: "1",
      cert_issue_date: "12/04/2017",
      cert_expiry_date: "12/09/2017"
    },
    {
      cert_id: "2",
      cert_issue_date: null,
      cert_expiry_date: "01/31/2018"
    },
    {
      cert_id: "3",
      cert_issue_date: null,
      cert_expiry_date: "02/02/2018"
    }
  ]
}
```

**OUTPUT SCREENSHOT**

[image: Pie Chart Output]

Comment: show what you have done ?

Comment: My Friend you need to parse the data from json on in the array of entity and then you can mange it and assign it to the chart datasource.

Comment: @AbdulRehmanWarraich I have updated my question. Please have a look

Comment: User map https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43518493/array-from-specific-keys-in-a-dictionaries-array

Comment: @HarshalBhavsar Ok thank You. But as I am new to app development, I am not familiar with JSON data and Alamofire. So please can you help me?

Comment: Hope this can help you
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YY3bTxgxWss

Comment: what is the output of above code ??

Comment: @AbdulRehmanWarraich Attached code output

Comment: you are sending these value " [25.0, 45.0, 36.0]" and pie chart is showing those values, Only now you have to get values from JSON and use then instead of these "[25.0, 45.0, 36.0]"

Comment: @AbdulRehmanWarraich Exactly. But I don't know how to do it as I have tried out my way.

Comment: share JSON then

Comment: i have mentioned the JSON above the screenshot

Comment: explain OUT chart value

Comment: Hey Saurabh did the video worked for you and helped you to learn it

Comment: yes it did worked for me